# Is there a way to hide a certain element from nth-child an on with css?

Tags: html, css

I have a div full with uncertain number of div's.
I would like to hide from, for example, div number 3 an on with css.

Is there a css rule for that?

Example:

```
<div class="elements-wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
.elements-wrapper div:nth-child(2) ~ div { display: none; }
```

The `~` is known as the general sibling combinator. Basically, it affects all proceding (not preceding) siblings (of the selector before the `~`) identified by the part after the `~`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, by using `nth-child()`

```css
/* hide all from the 4th element*/
.elements-wrapper > *:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements-wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @hao-wu, that will do :)